# Passing Command Line Arguments to EXE

Tags: windows, command-line, java, command-line-arguments

I am using the java `jar` utility which does not supoort extracting to specific directories via command line argument.  Therefore, I need to cd into the folder I want the extracted jar files to go into.
This means that I have to refer to the jar.exe file from a directory which is NOT the `bin` directory of Java.  Whenever I try something like: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45"jar`, it REFUSES to accept any arguments.  The program just prints out usage information, *no matter what*.

I even created a `.cmd` file:

```
SET %*
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\"jar.exe %*
```

No dice.  This is incredibly frustrating...
I've heard I can extract it like a zip file, but I'm not sure. I suppose when I re`jar` I'll have to use -m to use the manifest file that came with the jar.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo but...`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45"jar` is not valid syntax, the correct syntax is `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jar.exe"`. Try it first with `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jar.exe -foo"` or `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jar.exe" -foo` (i.e. I'm not sure if the quotes should enclose the argument, so try it both ways).

Comment: @CalebXu - Quotes in the middle of the path will not harm anything. I don't recommend doing it that way, but it still should work.